# Extract env variables from file using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, variables, logic

```
# code

ENV['VAR_1'] = 'HELLO 1'
ENV['VAR_2'] = 'HELLO 2'
ENV['VAR_3'] = 'HELLO 3'

# code
```

How do I extract using ruby and regex each variable and it's value?

Currently I'm doing line by line which is stupid.

```
S3_SECRET       = line.split(' = ').last.delete("'") if line =~ /ENV\['S3_SECRET'\]/
S3_KEY          = line.split(' = ').last.delete("'") if line =~ /ENV\['S3_KEY'\]/
S3_BUCKET       = line.split(' = ').last.delete("'") if line =~ /ENV\['S3_BUCKET'\]/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have quite a verbose regex like

```
/^ENV\['(.*?)'\] *= *'(.*?)'$/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/oDjqkP3HyW).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `ENV\['`  - a literal `ENV['` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the first
- `'\]` - literal `']` text
- `*= *` - a `=` sign enclosed with optional (0 or more) spaces
- `'` - a single quote
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the
- `'`  - final `'` at...
- `$` - the end of the line.

Here is a [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/9798A7):

```
s = <<DATA
# code

ENV['VAR_1'] = 'HELLO 1'
ENV['VAR_2'] = 'HELLO 2'
ENV['VAR_3'] = 'HELLO 3'

# code
DATA
puts s.scan(/^ENV\['(.*?)'\] *= *'(.*?)'$/).to_h
```

Output: `{"VAR_1"=>"HELLO 1", "VAR_2"=>"HELLO 2", "VAR_3"=>"HELLO 3"}`

Comment: You rock awesome !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you've read the file into an array of lines (using, say, [IO#readlines](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines)).

```
arr = ["ENV['VAR_1'] = 'HELLO 1'",
       "ENV['VAR_2'] = 'HELLO 2'",
       "ENV['VAR_3'] = 'HELLO 3'"]
```

Rather than using a complex regex straight away, we can remove the text we don't want, `split` the slimed-down strings on `"="`, surrounded by spaces, and then convert the resultant array to a hash.

```
bad_bits = %w| ENV[ ] ' |
  #=> ["ENV[", "]", "'"] 
r = Regexp.union(bad_bits)
  #=> /ENV\[|\]|'/ 
arr.map { |str| str.gsub(r, '') }.map { |s| s.split(/\s+=\s+/) }.to_h
  #=> {"VAR_1"=>"HELLO 1", "VAR_2"=>"HELLO 2", "VAR_3"=>"HELLO 3"}
```

Notice that [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html) does the escaping of regex's special characters for you.